# How to put result from Async class to mainActivity EditText

Tags: java, android

how do i access

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //result
    }
```

from mainActivity?
i wan to set EditText to result

```
final MainActivity mContext=new MainActivity();
EditText showresult=(EditText)mContext.findViewById(R.id.xx);
```

above codes does not show the control from mainActivity.

**updated code**

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        EditText ed=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.displayQue);
        ed.setText(result);

    }
```

---

```
09-03 15:31:19.882: D/AndroidRuntime(17146): Shutting down VM
09-03 15:31:19.882: W/dalvikvm(17146): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d45930)
09-03 15:31:19.992: E/AndroidRuntime(17146): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-03 15:31:19.992: E/AndroidRuntime(17146): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
09-03 15:31:19.992: E/AndroidRuntime(17146):    at com.example.digiqueue.MainActivity$ftpfunctions.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:106)
09-03 15:31:19.992: E/AndroidRuntime(17146):    at com.example.digiqueue.MainActivity$ftpfunctions.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
09-03 15:31:19.992: E/AndroidRuntime(17146):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
09-03 15:31:19.992: E/AndroidRuntime(17146):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
09-03 15:31:19.992: E/AndroidRuntime(17146):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
09-03 15:31:19.992: E/AndroidRuntime(17146):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-03 15:31:19.992: E/AndroidRuntime(17146):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
09-03 15:31:19.992: E/AndroidRuntime(17146):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5365)
09-03 15:31:19.992: E/AndroidRuntime(17146):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-03 15:31:19.992: E/AndroidRuntime(17146):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-03 15:31:19.992: E/AndroidRuntime(17146):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
09-03 15:31:19.992: E/AndroidRuntime(17146):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
09-03 15:31:19.992: E/AndroidRuntime(17146):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: put your async inside mainactivity , then u can .

Comment: You can't instantiate your Activity.

Comment: Kathir: i will try that.

Comment: Hi , it is giving me source code not found error.i put my async class inside mainactivity class. i updated the code

Comment: source code not found error? can u post the stacktrace

Comment: updated the error log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read the stacktrace

```
E/AndroidRuntime(17146): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
```

it seems that you have an `TextView` in you layout xml but trying to use it as `EditText` in your code. that won't work. you either have to change the xml to use `EditText` or your code to use `TextView`

i assume that you only want to display the result so you should use the `TextView` (an `EditText` is a text input box where the user can type text)

you code should look like this

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.displayQue);
    tv.setText(result);
}
```

good luck. :)

Answer (score 0):

Steps could be following:

1. Create an `interface` ResultListener with method `onResult(String result)`
2. Let MainActivity implement that interface
3. Pass MainActivity as one parameter for the `AsyncTask`
4. Save the ResultListener as member for the `AsyncTask`
5. Trigger `onResult` in `onPostExecute` for the ResultListener member
6. Show result got in `onResult` in your `EditText`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **adapters** to accomplish this.

Call your asynch method from`public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` method.